# How To Programmatically Set Text Displayed In UITableViewCell

Tags: c#, uitableview, mono, xamarin.ios

This seems as if it should be a FAQ-type question but for the life of me I can't seem to find this in any of the examples and searching other resources has also turned up bupkis.

Can someone share some example code to programmatically set the text displayed on a UITableViewCell in Monotouch?  I see a method in the UITableViewCell class to get the current text of the cell but I don't see anything to set it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
yourcell.TextLabel.Text = "Hello World!";
```

Comment: Thanks so much Geoff--I figured it had to be something simple.